# Separable subspaces in dual spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ be a separable closed subspace of $X^{*}$. Is there a separable closed subspace $Z$ of $X$ such that $Y$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $Z^{*}$? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Take a countable dense subset $A$ in $Y$. For each element $a\in A$ take a countable sequence $x_n$ in a unit ball of $X$ such that $a(x_n)$ tends to $\|a\|$. Let $Z$ be a closed span of all these sequences.

Comment: Thanks, Fedor! Indeed, we can choose $Z$ so that $Y$ is $(1+\epsilon)$-isomorphic to a subspace of $Z^{*}$.

Comment: Is not it even isometric?

Comment: I am not sure that it is isometric. Could you give a detailed proof?

Comment: The norm of each element in the unit ball of $Y$ exceeds $1-\varepsilon$ in $Z^{*}$, yes?

Comment: You are right, Fedor.